# msqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysqli, echo, fetch

I'm trying to query the DB with mysqli and then fetch the result, but it's throwing an Object of class could not be converted to a string error.

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:

```
<?php
include ('conn.php');

$query= "select value from the_table where item = 'url'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
```

And then I am trying to populate a link with the `$result`:

```
<a href="<?php echo $result; ?>">This is the Link to the URL</a>
```

I saw this post: [PHP and MySQL error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195840/php-and-mysql-error-object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-str)

So, I tried to format the echo with `echo $result->fetch_object()->url;`, but that didn't work.

I'm not sure if I have to fetch the result and then throw it into a look with a `mysqli_fetch_array()` and if so, how do I get it to populate that the value outside of the loop?

Comment: You need to `$row = mysqli_fetch($result)` to get a row, first.

Comment: you always first have to fetch the actual result using the fetch_array or fetch_object method. That is correct. However your `->url` part indicates that you have a selected column called `url` in your query. While in the query posted, you do not. Instead, what you wanted is echo `$result->fetch_object->value`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$db` is your database connection link you can perform the query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, 'select name from fruits');
```

Then you can get name using procedural style:

```
echo mysqli_fetch_object($result)->name;
```

Or object style:

```
echo $result->fetch_object()->name;
```

In your code you're trying to output `url` property which is not defined - as we can see in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:-

```
    $query= "select value from the_table where item = 'url'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query.");

    // use returned data
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row['value'];
    }
```

OR

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) )           
   {
      foreach ($row as $key => $value)
      {
     print ($row . " = " . $value . "\n");
      }
      print("================");
   }
```